# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'especialidad_id' doesn't have a default value?

Tags: laravel

mi problema es que a la hora de insertar los datos del usuario me sale este error[image: me dice que "especialidad_id" no tiene un valor definido]
Ese campo de "especialidad_id" es una llave foranea pero no la quiero llenar en el registro de usuarios ya que ese campo se llenara mas adelante despues de hacer el registro.

Estoy trabajando en laravel

Este es mi tabla de usuarios 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si agrego a un usuario desde codigo si me lo acepta la base de datos pero en la vista del formulario de registro de usuarios no agregue el campo de "especialidades_id" por que no lo quiero en ese formulario y ps a la hora de darle click en registrar es como me sale ese eror

¿Como le hago para evitar ese error?

Comment: Entonces en la definición no pongas `NOT NULL` y asígnale un valor `NULL` por defecto. ¿Podrías hacer un `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` para ver la definición?

Comment: Como dice @OscarGarcia hay un **conflicto** entre la forma en que definiste  a la columna `especialidad_id` y el `INSERT INTO` que estás implementando. Posiblemente no estás mencionando a esa columna en el `INSERT`, el manejador intenta asignarle un valor `NULL` y salta el error. Puedes quitarle la restricción `NOT NULL` a esa columna, o ponerle una valor por defecto, que será el que se inserte cuando la columna no se mencione en un `INSERT INTO...` Yo optaría por lo primero, pues es mejor dejar como `NULL` y no insertar cosas como cadenas vacías. Eso ya depende de ti y del uso de los datos.

Comment: Exacto, tal y como te dice @A.Cedano puedes solucionarlo indicando explícitamente un `NULL` para ese campo en el `INSERT` o bien poner el valor por defecto a `NULL` en la definición del campo. Eso siempre que permitas valores `NULL`, por eso necesitamos conocer la definición de la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas entiendo que en el formulario que comentas no necesitas la especialidad , entonces lo logico seria indicar a la columna de especialidad que puede ser nula :

```
$table->integer('especialidad_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ve directamente al phpMyAdmin, edita las columnas que quieres que queden vacías.

El procedimiento sería:

Click en cambiar la colmna, luego colocar en el atributo colocal NULL. Con eso te servirá.

Comment: Excelente observación. En este caso procede la primera respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que no tienes en tu modelo registrado el campo, `especialidad_id`
por eso cuando intentas hacer el `INSERT INTO` ese campo no se visualiza.

prueba agregarlo en el `protected $filltable`

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'apellido',
    'especialidad_id',
];
```